# can variables be declared with the "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example, for example, `this.x=5` and if they can be declared which places they all can be accessed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  this.x=!this.x;
    $("#div1").fadeTo(400,this.x ? 0.4 : 1);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are mixing up declaration and assignment of variables.

Comment: `and if they can be declared which places they all can be accessed` - anywhere `this` is the same `this` where they were assigned - in the code you posted, only inside the click handler - but since `this.x` will never be anything but undefined on entry, you're essentially just doing `$("#div1").fadeTo(400,0.4);` - since `this.x` will always end up `true` on click

Comment: You've not declared a variable `this` - when you enter the click event `this` is *already defined* - what you're doing is accessing a property of `this`.  If that property doesn't exist, javascript will create it for you.  So if your question meant *"can properties be added to `this`"* then - yes.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a variable using this keyword, here the scope of a variable differs that depends where we defined the variable.
For instance, we can define like this
this.x=10;
and now value of console.log(x) //10;
`this.x === this.x \\true
this.x == this.x \\true
this.x != this.x \\false`

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to declare variables in javascript. However it will work in some situations, attaching your variable to currect scope.